# Showing numbers 1 to 70 in VB.Net 2010

Tags: vb.net, string, vbscript, vb.net-2010, vb.net-to-c#

I would like to ask if who knows how to show numbers 1 up tp 70 in a `label` every time I click the button? To be specific, when I hit my Button "Next", automatically number 1 will show on my blank `label` and when I hit again my button it will change in number 2 and so on.

I used this code in my button:

```
Queue.Label1.Text = Queue.Label1.Text + 1
```

Comment: Kids, don't be lazy with your assignments. Show some effort.

Comment: take a book and search for the word "counter" then GUI elements and at the end MVVC

Comment: I used this code in my button Queue.label1.text= Queue.label1.text + 1    , but I get only 1 up to 9...it never continue to number 10 up to 70..

Comment: Include that code in your question. Don't put it here in the comments section. :)

Comment: ok sir.. I'm really sorry.. :)

Comment: No problem. Just read the site's _How to Ask_ guide. Re your question: What is `Queue`? Is it a form?

Comment: Yes sir, it is a form..

Comment: sir I'm very thankful.. it works... thank you very much....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first of all `Label1.Text` is a `String`. It will be problematic to you to perform math operations using a `String`.

You can try:

`Queue.Label1.Text = Val(Queue.Label1.Text) + 1`

`Val()` returns a numeric value.

Now, to limit it up to 70 only, you just have to put an `if` condition:

```
If Val(Queue.Label1.Text) < 70 Then
     Queue.Label1.Text = Val(Queue.Label1.Text) + 1
End If
```

EDIT:

Changed `If` condition from `<=` to `<`.

Comment: `Val(Queue.Label1.Text) <= 70` that would ***allow more than 70***. Should be `Val(Queue.Label1.Text) < 70`. I don't think this was tested... Also on another note, `Kids, don't be lazy with your assignments...` why would you make a comment like this and then clearly post an answer as it defeats the whole purpose...

Comment: @Zaggler, yep, haven't tested it. And will make revisions re that. Regarding the remarks I made, you can read the whole comments section and see that the OP understood and edited his post, don't make assumptions without reading everything.

Comment: No assumptions, it's still there.

Comment: Should I delete it? I think it will be more helpful to leave it there. And for those arguing "why comment something like that then answering by himself?", they can see our conversation here then check the comments section of the post.

Comment: @Zaggler, by the way, I already edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out and I apologize for the careless mistake.

Comment: No it's ok! Thanks for editing it. The reason I mentioned it is because it could throw another person off with the same issue and the old way wasn't correct. Thanks again! +1 for the edit and solution.

Comment: @Zaggler, No, it is me who should thank you. :) Cheers!